# Changing the return value of md-datepicker in Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I have started to use Angular-Material. When I use the datepicker the returning date value has not just the date. It has time and other information like below

```
2016-05-08T18:30:00.000Z
```

I just need the date with out the other information. Is there a way to do that

this is the code

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="data.Date" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
```

controller code

```
 app.controller('cntrlr',function($scope){
    $scope.data = {};

    });
```

Comment: do you need the data in `date` or `string`

Comment: I can work with any format.

Comment: you need post some code..how do you do it.. so people can understand you better..

Comment: added the code as you asked. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried all the above things and due to my lack of knowledge in angular I failed miserably to succeed. The input I got was to my Web Api controller. What I did was I split the date value I'm getting from T.

```
string[] newdate = data.date.Split(T);
```

Then I assigned it to another string variable to get the split value which I wanted

```
string finaldate = newdate[0];
```

With this I got the date like "2016-05-17"

I'm not sure where this would help or this practice is acceptable. But I hope someone could benefit from this so I posted this. Thanks for the guys who help with the answers to this question too.

Answer (score 2):

md-datepicker is parsing the date into your model, bound via "md-model" attribute. You can modify parsing / formatting behaviour via mdDateLocalProvider. Check out documentation at https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDateLocaleProvider

As I might not got your question 100% correctly, you could also handle the parsed date after it has been bound to your scopes model by registering a handler using the "ng-change" attribute of the md-datepicker directive. E.g.

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="ctrl.yourDateModel"
               ng-change="ctrl.yourDateStringModel = ctrl.formatDate(ctrl.yourDateModel)">
```

Comment: can you please explain yourDateStringModel. I dont know what that is. Sorry for my ignorance. Im just a beginner

Comment: Just as I don't understand exactly your case, I thought a separate string-ish  value in your controllers scope could help you out. Some example or some further explanation of what you exactly want to  achieve could help to sort this out.

To explain my point: a function called "formatDate" in your controller could format your Date object into the format you specifically need and store it into the controller scope bound variable named "yourDateStringModel". You could then use this value to do whatever you want  (send to server, display, ...)

Comment: So what Im doing is that, I have created a scope object `$scope.data = {}`
What I'm trying to do is pass the value of date to this object along with some other data
in my datepicker what im doing is as follows

`<md-datepicker ng-model="data.date" md-placeholder="Enter></md-datepicker>`

when I run this a date value is passed to `$scope.data` object through `data.date` model. The original value i get is `2016-05-08T18:30:00.000Z` what I want is `2016-05-08`

Comment: The thing is that I can't use a separate object just to store the date value but what I want is to send value of the date as an attribute of this object

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/smallyin/mrp3qxgq/4/)**

If your html:

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="distributionOV.SelectFromDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
```

By angular way :

```
.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.distributionOV={};

    $scope.$watch('distributionOV', function(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (!newVal.SelectFromDate) {
        return false;
      }
      var date = $filter('date')(new Date(newVal.SelectFromDate), "yyyy-MM-dd");
      alert(date);
    },true);
  });
```

Notice `myDate` is binding to `$scope`, when you end your date pick, it should have the value you choosed.

Comment: the thing is that I'm getting few data values to a javascript object. So I dont know how to access that data like this.

$scope.data = {}
when a button is pressed all the data from the form gets into this object

Comment: But for the ng-model I'm using

`ng-model ="data.date"`

i have `$scope.data = {}`

Comment: @TharinduSenanayake, use `$watch` to catch the event when user finish pick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.dateValue = "2016-05-08T18:30:00.000Z"
var split_date = $scope.dateValue.split('T');
$scope.date = split_date[0];
```

Comment: the thing is that I'm getting few data values to a javascript object. So I dont know how to access that data like this.

$scope.data = {}
when a button is pressed all the data from the form gets into this object

Comment: can you share the object you are getting in your `$scope.data`

Comment: this is the object

`Object {SelectFromDate: Mon May 16 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time), Location: "Apple", SecB: "B", SecA: "A", SecC: "C"}`

Answer (score -1):

```
    app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $filter,) { 

  $scope.$watch("dateValue", function(newValue, oldValue){  
     $scope.dateValue= $filter('date')(newValue, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
  });

});
```

Comment: While this may be a good answer, code should always come with some kind of explanations as to why that code works. Thanks!